# How to call this function devtools selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-devtools-protocol

I am trying to call this method in the devtools protcol [Network.setRequestInterception](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-setRequestInterception). So Far I have this:

```
IDevTools devTools = driver as IDevTools;
DevToolsSession session = devTools.CreateDevToolsSession();
session.Network.Enable(new OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.Network.EnableCommandSettings());
session.Network.SetRequestInterception(new OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.Network.SetRequestInterceptionCommandSettings() {
            //Patterns = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<AccountDetails>>(json);
            Patterns = new RequestPattern[] { new ResourceType {"Image" }  }



        }
```

I cant figure out how to call it with the correct paraneters. In the documentation, it shows the type of object it is but it is different in the selenium code. It uses [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/DevTools/AutoGenerated/Network/RequestPattern.cs) as one of the parameters and [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/DevTools/AutoGenerated/Network/SetRequestInterceptionCommand.cs) as the function.

I am trying to call the setRequestInterception with the resourceType Image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line of code:

```
Patterns = new RequestPattern[] { new ResourceType {"Image" }  }
```

Is trying to assign a ResourceType object into a RequestPattern array.

Instead, try:

```
Patterns = new RequestPattern[] { new RequestPattern() { ResourceType = ResourceType.Image } }
```

In your array, create a request pattern object first, and in that assign the resource type.